# Java Inheritance

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Iam writing a simple Java program for an assignment,which implements a library system using inheritance.I have a class named Entry and two others who extend it (book and journal).

Everything works fine.

Now i must create a class which will test the whole program.This class should use an array to store the elements (books OR journals which i want to add in the system).I don't know how many elements i will add but i must declare an array for them (either my entry will be book,or journal).My question is:This array should be an Entry array (as i suppose) and if yes,if for example i want to add a book the extra elements that Book has where will be stored?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should add to an `Entry` array. You can add `Book` instance to the `Entry` array since it is extending `Entry`. To access the properties or methods of `Book` after getting it from `Entry` array, you have to cast it to `Book`.

```
Entry[] entries = new Entry[5];
entries[0] = new Book();
Book aBook = (Book)entries[0];
aBook.getBookTitle();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare this array for Entry

```
Entry array[] = new Entry[10];
array[0] = new book();
array[1] = new journal();
```

That works just fine.

In java you don't have the actual object in a variable, but a pointer to it, that's why you need to make ***new Object*** it asks for the memory it needs for said Object.

Comment: Ok thanks!I have done that but i didn't knew if book in array[0] for example keeps the elements that are properties of book (which extends Entry) and not Entry.
Thank you very much again!:)